# Making a template class with linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new to linked list and I will make a phonebook program. I need to store the contacts info in a linked list: last name , first name , street address, city, state, zipcode, and phone number. But after i store them in the list i want to sort each contact by last name. I'm not sure if i should create a standard linked list class or make a linked list template? 
Edit: I need to use linked list for my assignment . i dont understand linked list that well. I thought creating it manually would help my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, it should not be necessary (unless out of interest or special requirements) to implement a linked list manually, as it is already contained in the standard library, as documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/); apparently sorting is also implemented.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is imo not a good choice for a phonebook. You probably want to sort your list for faster lookups, but a linked list still requires O(n) due to the lack of random access iterators. My advice is to use a `std::vector` or implement something similar if you want to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer `std::list`. It exists, is well tested and already provides a `sort()` method:

```
auto l = std::list<Contact>{};
// fill list
l.sort([](const Contact& first, const Contact& second){
           return std::less(first.lastName, second.lastName);
       });
```

As a rule of thumb most of the time it is better to use the standard templates than to try and reinvent the wheel.

BTW.: reconsider, if a linked list really is the best container for your needs. Sometimes it is, but often it is not.